# Yet another difficulty with PrimeFaces 3.0.M4 file uploading

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, file-upload, primefaces

So, the question is quite widespread. I want to upload file to the server using `p:fileUpload` in `mode="simple"` ([showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/fileUploadSimple.jsf)). There are a lot of questions and answers about problems with file uploading on forums, but I failed to found comprehensive one. File upload component are in `/faces/second.xhtml`:

```
<h:form>
    <p:wizard>
        <p:tab id="firstStep" title="First step">
            <ui:include src="/faces/first.xhtml" />
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab name="secondStep" title="Second step">
            <ui:include src="/faces/second.xhtml" />
        </p:tab>
    </p:wizard>
</h:form>
```

Where `/faces/second.xhtml` contains:

```
<p:panel>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="file">
        <p:fileUpload value="#{tutorialBean.thumbnail}" mode="simple" />
        <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="growl"
            actionListener="#{tutorialBean.thumbnailUpload}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

Bean:

```
@SessionScoped
public class TutorialBean {
    private UploadedFile thumbnail;

    public void thumbnailUpload(){
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, 
             "File uploaded", thumbnail.getFileName());  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg); 
    }

    // setters and getters
}
```

I've added FileUpload filter to `web.xml`:

```
<!-- PrimeFaces file upload -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
        <param-value>100000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
        <param-value>C:\Users\name\Desktop\</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

And I've added `commons-io` (2.0.1) and `commons-fileupload` (1.2.2) to my `pom.xml`. According to solutions I've found it must work, but it don't. `thumbnail` is `null` during `thumbnailUpload` execution.
I'm using primefaces 3.0.M4, jBoss as 7.0.2.Final

Thanks in advance

**Solved:** The problem was not in `fileUpload` component, but in form at page which was included as part of the main page. I've added `prependId="false"` to the inner form and everything works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first with the simple/standard Primefaces filter:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
```

I don't really know why it doesn't work this for you. I tried the simple and the advanced mode and both works just fine. Also if you use the advanced mode you can use an action method that receives `FileUploadEvent event` as a param and it's easier this way:

```
String fileName = "Uploaded_"+event.getFile().getFileName();
        System.out.println("Uploaded: " + fileName);
```

UPDATE:

Because you have only the fileupload in the second step, you could try something like this.

```
<p:wizard>
    <p:tab id="firstStep" title="First step">
      <h:form>
        <ui:include src="/faces/first.xhtml" />
      </h:form>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab name="secondStep" title="Second step">
        <p:panel>
          <h:form multipart>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="file">
                <p:fileUpload value="#{tutorialBean.thumbnail}" mode="simple" />
                <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="growl"
                    actionListener="#{tutorialBean.thumbnailUpload}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
          </h:form>
        </p:panel>
    </p:tab>
</p:wizard>
```

Comment: It looks like that a problem is in the nested forms. I don't know how to use file upload with `form enctype="multipart/form-data"` inside another, main form. Have you any suggestions?

Comment: @nikagra Post here(update/edit question) your entire xhtml page to see if you really need the 'nested forms'...maybe you can close a form and open another.

Comment: So, it seems like the problem is with forms and `ui:include`. I've updated question

Comment: @nikagra It seems fileUpload should work in version 3. Look at this closed issue: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1891

Comment: Also this topic might be of help: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1546

Comment: I've added `prependId="false"` attribute to the form inside included page and it works now. Thanks for you help!

Comment: @nikagra Glad I could be of help!